# How do I conveniently reveal/expand sublevels in outline view of interface builder dock in Xcode4

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder

I have several table columns embedded in a table view embedded in a scroll view embedded in larger view embedded in a tab view embedded in another view embedded in a window.

When click on the nib file in Xcode 4, the Editor pane shows me the Interface Builder dock in an outline view.  Typically, I'd like to set the Cocoa bindings for the table columns.

To get to the table columns, I have to open many levels of subtrees, sequentially. If I click on a column header in the graphical view, and I get lucky, it takes me to the table header.  In this case, I only have to open one more level, the table view.  When I run my project in the debugger, and come back to the nib file, I have to do it all over again.

Is if there a way to expand all sublevels of the outline view in the IB dock with a single command, or to expand sublevels under a selected level ?

EDIT: Not an answer, but a workaround: double click the nib file to open it in a separate window. The window won't be affected by switching files in the main window. Another feature I was unaware of is Xcode 4's tab capability (Command-T) - works like a tabbed browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking on the disclosure triangle at the appropriate level.

Comment: Holding ALT button is enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fast forwarding several years, it looks like with Xcode 11.6, you now hold <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> key while clicking on the disclosure triangle.